# Maven build using embedded JAR in project pom

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I am working on a Maven project where a build is done through Jenkins, and 1 particular JAR has been removed from corporate repository recently.

So my build is failing as parent pom.xml is referring to a JAR not available in the repo.

But I have the old certified copy downloaded in my local repo, and I want to use the same JAR during build copying in the project folder and want to use the local copy of dependent JAR in pom.xml instead of downloading from corporate repository embedded in the project structure.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this does not sound like a good idea.

While it is possible to reference jars with the `<systemPath>` entry, it is generally considered bad practise.

By "corporate repository", do you mean a repository of your own company or of some other company? In the first case, you should request that the jar is put back in. In the second case, it would be better not to use the external corporate repository directly, but to set up your own Nexus/Artifactory through which you use (different) external repositories. This Nexus/Artifactory can then host additional artifacts like the one you need (you can e.g. upload them through the UI).

Comment: Thanks for your response....System path did not help much with Jenkins & Jules...So it is not a solution... I tried to create a local repo in the project codebase....that is working in local but not in cloud and jenkins..... So still searching for a solution...

Comment: Could you please clarify if "corporate repository" means the Nexus/Artifactory of your own company or an external repository?